# NSDateFormatter formatting issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I am trying to convert `NSString` into `NSDate` in 12 hours format. (in iOS 6)

Code :

```
NSString *Bdt = @"05/23/2012 08:00 AM"
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *bd = [df dateFromString:Bdt];
NSLog(@"%@",bd);
```

Output:

> 2012-05-23 08:00:00 +0000 it should be 2012-05-23 08:00 AM

Whats wrong in the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Nothing wrong here. If you NSLog a NSDate (i.e. call `description` on it) you will get `2012-05-23 08:00:00 +0000`.

Comment: You are getting 08:00AM

Comment: @MatthiasBauch: yes but it should be `2012-05-23 08:00 AM`

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: no I am getting `2012-05-23 08:00:00 +0000`

Comment: @user1859900: chck my answr

Comment: Down votes for what ?

Comment: @user1859900: I didn't down vote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want date in `2012-05-23 08:00 AM` style

Create a dateformatter and setDateFormat as `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a`

```
NSString *Bdt = @"05/23/2012 08:00 AM";
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] ;
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *bd = [df dateFromString:Bdt];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter  setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a" ];
NSString *datestr=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:bd];
NSLog(@"%@",datestr);
```

*Note : I am using ARC, so objects are not released/autoreleased.

*EDIT:*

`NSDate` will be in this format ONLY : `2012-05-23 08:00:00 +0000`.

For any other format you need to use `NSString`.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: I am not asking for NSString ! I just want to make a date from the string !!! do NSLog(@"%@", bd);

Comment: @user1859900: you can't get customized NSDate output. NSDate contains timezone from gmt. so there is only one way to do by NSString.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong with it. You are printing an NSDate in NSLog which is very different than creating an NSString with a specific format.

It seems your confusing the internal NSDate representation with string formatting. NSDate stores the date internally in a way different from how it is represented by humans. Just like NSString stores strings in a format that may not be what you ultimately want it encoded as, eg. ASCII or UTF-8. When you are calling NSLog you are getting a diagnostic message showing the date according to the string returned by `- (NSString *)description` or possibly `- (NSString *)debugDescription`.